# Appium tap(int x, int y) function seems to be deprecated. Any replacements?

Tags: java, appium

I'm trying to automate an Android game and for that I'm using X,Y co-ordinates to make a button click, as identifying elements through ID, Xpath etc. is not possible for games. I'm using TouchAction tap(int x, int y) method (Appium Method) for achieving this. But unfortunately this method tap(int x, int y) seems to be deprecated. The other options replacing this looks to be --> touchAction.tap(PointOptions tapOptions) and touchAction.tap(TapOptions tapOptions). The same is the case with touchAction.press as well.

My code to touch a specific button looks like this:

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.tap(1280, 1013).perform();
```

Here, the X,Y values are found using Touch points in Android Device [Developer Options > Show pointer location]

Can anyone suggest a better way to achieve the same using non deprecated method? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can view the TouchAction documentation here:

https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html

Here's the method that replaced the tap() you are using:

https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html#tap-io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption-

and here is the PointOption documentation, which is the new parameter to use with tap():

https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/touch/offset/PointOption.html

So to answer your question, you have two choices with PointOption:

1. Using PointOption.point(x, y), which is a static instance of PointOption with those coordinate values

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.tap(PointOption.point(1280, 1013)).perform()
```

2. Using PointOption().withCoordinates(x, y), which returns a reference to the PointOption instance after setting those coordinate values

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates(1280, 1013)).perform()
```

Comment: I am getting an error for the first choice as "Method has not yet been implemented" what would be the cause?

Comment: Resolved my Issue

Comment: I am getting the same error even using the above code.

Using PointOption.point(x, y), which is a static instance of PointOption with those coordinate values

Answer (score 0):

As different Options are introduced after an update , This will Work for you

```
new TouchAction(driver).tap(PointOption.point(x,y)).waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(duration))).moveTo(PointOption.point(x, y)).release().perform();

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to the deprecated tap/press function is the 'longPress' function. Here's the function :

```
public T longPress(LongPressOptions longPressOptions) {
    ActionParameter action = new ActionParameter("longPress", longPressOptions);
    parameterBuilder.add(action);
    //noinspection unchecked
    return (T) this;
}
```

For more information, see : https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.java

Comment: So, in this function, where should I pass the X,Y coordinates. What parameters does the (LongPressOptions longPressOptions) accept? There is another tap function which is not deprecated as far as I read from Eclipse [touchAction.tap(PointOptions tapOptions) and touchAction.tap(TapOptions tapOptions).] but I'm unaware what needs to be passed as its parameters.